# How to generate telerik header and datafields dynamically in a report

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-reporting

I have a scenario whereby i need to display different headers and datafields based on different users in a telerik report.Here is the case:'School A' has like 6 subjects which are examined and School B got 8 subjects which are examined.I wanted to know how i can generate the headers and datafields on runtime in the telerik report without displaying some subjects which are not taught in other schools such that when it loads, i can have those headers and datafields generated from my code behind since from my code i can get those different subjects for each school.
Any idea i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem something like to this scenario. It is print different tax types and values dynamically to each customer for their invoices. So this answer based on that.

In your case, make a list with your own subjects. List should contain 6 subject to school A and 8 subject to school B. Then add a sub report to your main report. Pass your list to sub report. It will bind any number of subjects dynamically as your requirement.

In your main report

```
   List<subject> SubjectList = new List<subject>();
      subject a = new subject();
      a.subjectName= "a";
      SubjectList.Add(a);

  subReport1.ReportSource = new subjectSubReport(SubjectList);
```

In your sub report

```
public subjectSubReport(List<subject> subjects)
    {           
        InitializeComponent();

            if (subjects.Count > 0){

            var apiOutput = new{

                invoceRpt = subjects.Select(a => new{
                   subjects = a.subjectName,                       
                })
            };
                this.DataSource = apiOutput.invoceRpt;                   
            }
   }
```

You may help this link also.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/867359/Pass-Parameters-from-Web-Page-to-Telerik-Report